# Firebase Is there a way to add multiple users into one UID

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am new to Android and would like to add two different kind of user into one project UID: one is the supervisor and the other one is the moderator.

But I can't figure out how to do it is there a way to do so. How can I do it?

This is my Firebase database:

[image: This is my Firebase Database]

Comment: What you had done already? Show your code.

Answer (score 1):

You are going about it in a wrong way. Each user is given a unique UID. save those in your database as

```
users : 
      uid1 : 
          email: ****
          role: moderator 

     uid2 : 
         email: ****
         role: supervisor 
    ...
```

or if one person can have multiple roles you can use flags like this:

```
users : 
      uid1 : 
          email: ****,
          isMod: true,
          isSup: false, 
     uid2 : 
         email: ****,
         isMod: true, 
         isSup: true,
    ...
```

So for instance, uid2 is both moderator and supervisor but uid1 is only moderator. You can always access roles and know who is who when you need it. Please try to read [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data) about best practices for your database. In short, try not to make your database deep. 
Also, I recommend looking at [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/) if you are new. So you choose which database to use before getting into one to avoid need of migration later.

Comment: Because for my program both moderator and supervisor can access the same project and insert different mark to the project, that why i put two role under project. Or are there anyway i can done this?

Comment: Yes, like my examples, you have to save roles per each user under a node (call it users for example). Later, when a user wants to perform an action you can check the role for that user to determine if that user has the credentials or the needed role or not. The examples I gave you solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

UID is Unique Id and you cannot have two users with same UID.
Yes you can identify users by managing the firebase database. 
For example:

```
"UserName 1" : 
            "email" : "emailId",
            "userType" : "customer"

"UserName 2" : 
            "email" : "emailId",
            "userType" : "vendor"
```

Use above pattern. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [custom user claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) on the user to define whether they are supervisor or moderator.

You would set the custom claims via Admin SDK:

```
admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, {role: 'moderator'}).then(() => {
  // The new custom claims will propagate to the user's ID token the
  // next time a new one is issued.
});
```

You can then enforce access via security rules without having to do any lookup:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "data": {
      "$user_id": {
        ".read": "$user_id === auth.uid",
        // Write access only for moderator.
        ".write": "auth.token.role === 'moderator'"
      }
    }
  }
}
```